# destroy session after page reload laravel

Tags: laravel, session

When I load the home page of my website for the first time it shows a modal that fetches a book from the database. I want the following functionality

1. This modal should disappear on subsequent reloads.
2. When the home page is opened in a new tab, the modal should be shown.

I am able to this using a front-end check-in JS. But I want to do it from the server side. That is, during subsequent reloads I don't want it to look for the book in the database.

Here's how I'm trying to implement this:

```
if (session('book_modal_has_shown')) {
    $unreadBook = null;
} else {
    $unreadBook = Book::getRandomUnreadBook();
    session()->flash('book_modal_has_shown', true);
}
return view('home')->with(['book' => $unreadBook]);
```

Comment: you can try `if(session()->has('bookRead')) { $unreadBook = null;} else { session('bookRead', true); //load unread book here }`

Comment: this works fine in a single tab. but when I open it in a new tab it does not show the modal because 'bookRead' is true and it does not load the book.

Comment: is there some way that a new session starts in a new tab?

Comment: @Abhishek All tabs with same url shares one session. Not showing modal in new tab is correct, i think.

Comment: @Abhishek all tabs share the same session, if you have to close the browser then only new session

Comment: This is different from how JavaScript `sessionStorage` object works?